Package pdftex Error: File 'Fig_6Z.jpg' not found. An older jpg works ok
With pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.12.10)  10 APR 2024 19:23,
and using latest TeXShop 5.31 under MacOS 12.7.4 (MacPro 2013),
two jpg files were exported from Keynote,
the newer jpg with Keynote  13.1 (7037.0.101).
The older jpg produced some months back works fine.
A similar recent jpg (similar and in the same directory as the test tex source file), fails.
This is happening with several newly produced jpgs.
Ditto with png files.
Changing color profiles from Display P3 to sRGB IEC61966-2.1 did not help.
Advice will be appreciated.

Is the comma instead of the full stop a copy-and-paste problem, or is it the problem? :-;

...anyway, we need more data to help. A minimal example with the full log would be perfect!

So, the OP sent to me the code in a zip file.
In my home Linux (which is quite new; the problem is easier to spot in older Linux that has a buggy version of the Archive Manager app), I have:

and it seems all ok. Also, the listing seems ok:

...but if I try to list just the file, it errors out like your LaTeX:
$ ls Fig_6Z.jpg                                         
ls: cannot access 'Fig_6Z.jpg': No such file or directory

...but if I try to use shell expansion, for example, cat and then TAB, I have after a couple of pulses:

So the app you use is adding a Unicode Left-to-right marker!
Which it shouldn't. The problem is that this character is basically invisible...
To show it, you can use LANG=C ls -l:


Nice piece of detective work

Hi,
Exported images using Keynote 13.1 / macOS 12.7.4 on a Mac Pro 2013 now have corrupted file names.
Apple support recommends Keynote 14.1—not possible for  macOS Monterey on Mac Pro 2013.
Ditto MacBook Pro 2016.
Each file name needs a terminal command (kindly proposed by Romano):
mv *XYZ.jpg XYZ.jpg
ls -l    checks a directory's file names.

Nice, happy to know you've found the final answer... although it's not ideal. @BrianColeman, would you mind to accept the answer?
